# What type of tor node am I running?

Tags: mac

I'm new to tor. I'm wondering in my situation, whether other people can use my computer as a tor exit node or not.

I have my Mac (192.168.0.x) running OS X, connecting to my home router(192.168.0.1). I installed tor with homebrew `brew install tor`, and started tor with the `tor` command. Now I can configure my browser to have sock5 proxy (127.0.0.1:9050) to use the tor I started. Now I'm wondering what type of tor node my computer is running? Is there any chance my home router IP being logged by a website if other tor users accessed that website? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to browser anonymously, use Tor Browser. The other question is answered on here already...